# слайдер на чистом js. Плавное переключение картинок

Tags: javascript, css, слайдер

как сделать плавное переключение картинок слайдера? Пытался через css transition, но ничего не получилось. Прошу вашей помощи всезнающие, ибо без вас серьезно не смогу понять.

JS:

```
var image = ['картинка1', 'картинка2', 'картинка3'];
var num = 0;
function next(){
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    num++;
    if(num >= image.length){
        num = 0;
    }
    slider.src=image[num];
}
function prev(){
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    num--;
    if(num < 0){
        num= image.length-1;
    }
    slider.src=image[num];
}
```

CSS:

```
.button{
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 240px;
  width: 40vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
.section{
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 26.6vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button_p{
transition: 0.6s ease;
margin-top: -100%;
float: left;
width: 10%;
height: 1000px;
}
.button_n{
transition: 0.6s ease;
margin-top: -100%;
float: right;
width: 10%;
height: 1000px;
}
.imges{
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 240px;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 26.6vw;
}

.button_p:hover{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
.button_n:hover{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой transition не поможет, если сразу переключать src картинки (оно принимает только одно значение, нет промежуточных состояний для анимации).

Можно вставить все картинки в виде <img> в общий контейнер, позиционировать `absolute`, чтобы накладывались друг на друга и анимировать их `opacity`.

Надо обратить внимание, если у вас десятки огромных картинок, можно немного усложнить обработку: Сначала вставить одну статичную картинку, когда все важные части страницы загрузятся, только потом постепенно догрузить остальные картинки и запустить слайдер.

```js
let data = [
  "https://gyazo.com/f2483ea0884e464410faa0c84a552727.png",
  "https://gyazo.com/a5e892094cc05497b148e9e8c6b4763b.png",
  "https://gyazo.com/d58d893500f6551b155a1cb7b1099b74.png",
];

/***/
let slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let index = 0, images /* список <img> внутри slider */;

(function __init__() {
  slider.innerHTML = data.map(src => `<img src="${ src }">`).join("");
  
  images = slider.querySelectorAll("img");
  images[index].classList.add("opaque");
})();

function next() {
  images[index].classList.remove("opaque");
  index = (index + 1) % images.length;
  images[index].classList.add("opaque");
}

function prev() {
  images[index].classList.remove("opaque");
  index = (index - 1 + images.length) % images.length;
  images[index].classList.add("opaque");
}

(function _loop() {
  next();
  setTimeout(_loop, 4000);
})();
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
}

#slider img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

#slider img.opaque {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```